# Error en conexión a servidor con FTP

Tags: servidor, ftp, filezilla

Desde hace unos días he intentado conectarme a un servidor donde tengo alojado un sistema de información, las credenciales de ingreso las he modificado más de 10 veces y me constan de que están correctas, el error que me lanza filezilla es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No estás mostrando el error

Comment: Mira de nuevo la pregunta

Comment: Si el servidor FTP es tuyo, mira y/o muestranos los log. Si no lo es ... pues habla con soporte, atención al usuario, o lo que tengan

Comment: en 000webhost los cambios no se hacen imediato despues de hacer el cambio debes esperar minimo 1 hora me a pasado! si no puedes usar el filemanager !